# How pass a mouse event to an underlying element?

Tags: winforms, powershell

I've got a borderless movable form (dragged around by clicking and holding a mouse button). The dragging only works when I click on the form empty spaces, e.g. margin/padding area. How do I render a control (let's say label) so that it doesn't capture mouse events, but instead passes it to the underlying form element? In other words, I want to click on this label element and drag the form.
The closest thing I can think of is `pointer-events: none` in `CSS`.

Here's the powershell code I use to make my form movable:

```
function makeFormDraggable {
  param($form)
  Add-Type '
    using System;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

    public class User32{
        //const and dll functions for moving form
        public const int WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN = 0xA1;
        public const int HT_CAPTION = 0x2;

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, int wParam, int lParam);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern bool ReleaseCapture();
    }
  '
  $onMouseDown = [System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler] {
  #Event Argument: $_ = [System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs]
    [user32]::ReleaseCapture()
    [user32]::SendMessage($form.Handle, [user32]::WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN, [user32]::HT_CAPTION, 0);
  }
  $form.Add_MouseDown($onMouseDown)
}
```

Comment: The way I've done it in the past is to attach to the same event handler.

Comment: @Enigmativity, hey, thank you, I guess it would work

Comment: I am guessing this approach would work IF the form only contains controls that that user cannot edit. Using a `Label` as an example makes some sense in that the user typically does not edit the label, however, what if the user tries to type into a text box? This approach is going to have to distinguish the controls that you want the user to edit (like a text box), otherwise the user will never be able to “edit” the control. Just a thought.